# Which is the best place to handle the deleted data scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application where MVVM model is used. Also, we do have the requirement of showing some data in Dialog() using ShowDialog(). For this purpose, We have a MainWindow call another method in a different class which will actually return an object of type Window. The MainWindow will then show this window by calling the ShowDialog() method. The window class has ViewModel which will have the data that is displayed in the dialog.

My problem is How to handle the scenario where in the data is not present in the db ?

Should the constructor of the Window() or ViewModel(which one exactly) throw the exception ? If Yes then what type of exception ? Is there any other way of handle this scenario ?

Comment: Your user interface, windows, and whether you call ShowDialog or not, should not interfere with getting your data and whether it is present or not in MVVM. You should separate your UI and data access logic

Comment: I suppose only the OP can decide whether the above comment applies or not, but in the case that you do have a data access layer and that layer is returning no data, it sounds feasible that your UI should know about this and should raise the appropriate notification to the user. It's up to you how the error is handled, but obviously writing the same error handling popup for multiple windows would be a waste - I suppose you could use some sort of aggregator which sat at the MainWindow VM level and intercepted these exceptional circumstances and displayed an appropriate message in a popup

Comment: Try to show better your specification, from where the information you show from, if it is from DB, there is no problem because is from the DB, if not maybe you should add to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't laying out the use case so yo aren't going to get the best answer, because the answer DEPENDS on your use case, your domain and your users.

That said it's highly unlikely that you want your users to see an exception, even if it is in fact exceptional. Better to either show the dialog with an informative message (ie, "No Items to Display") or just not show it at all.

HTH,
Berryl